# How to fix 'Invalid regular expression' using rails google analytics api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, google-analytics-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to use a regular expression in a pagePath filter but I always get a 'bad request' response, even though it's a well-formed regex (I tested it separately)

```
my_regex = /\/\w{2}\/someword(\/?|\/.+)(\?.*)?$/
filter = "ga:pagePath=~#{my_regex}"

#GAApiClient (V3) execute parameters
'filters' => filter
```

I also tried writing the regex directly in the filter string but I got the same result

```
filter = "ga:pagePath=~\/\w{2}\/someword(\/?|\/.+)(\?.*)?$"
```

There's a specific way to write the regex inside the filter?

The google documentation falls short on that subject
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters

Comment: I think `\w` might not be supported [docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en) (I have no idea though, never used this before). You could also try URL encoding the regex before sending it to Google. As a general rule for debugging, just keep taking stuff out until something works, and add stuff in until it fails. That should narrow it down a little.

Comment: Try it here https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/.